# Extract Local Maxima

Tags: code-golf, array

Given an array of positive integers, output an array of all the elements that are greater than or equal to the adjacent ones. Most elements will have two adjacent elements; the first and last element are special cases, as they only have one adjacent element.

You may assume that the array contains at least two elements.

Test cases:

```
Input               | Output
[4,2,6,12,4,5,4,3]  | [4,12,5]
[1,2]               | [2]
[1,2,3,2,1]         | [3]
[3,2,1,2,3]         | [3,3]
[4,4]               | [4,4]
[2,4,4,4,1]         | [4,4,4]
[2,3,3,4]           | [3,4]
[4,3,3,4]           | [4,4]
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code wins!

Comment: @PeterTaylor I think what's meant is "For the first or last element to be included in the output, ..."

Comment: @PeterTaylor xnor is correct.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/68967/194)

Comment: Also related: [Finding Local Extremes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/22252/11354)

Comment: Can I propose `[4,3,3,4]` as a testcase. My solution didn't handle that one very well sadly.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam Done

Comment: I've voted to close this as a duplicate of [Finding Local Extremes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/22252/finding-local-extremes) as this is a subset of that challenge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13 12</s>  11 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
0;;0»3\f"⁸Ẏ
```

A monadic link taking a list of positive integers and returning the filtered list containing only those which are greater than or equal to all their neighbours.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/A2trg0G7jmDSlR407Hu7q@///f7SJjpGOmY6hkY6JjikQG8cCAA)**

---

Previous [12 byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/A2tPv6B5PO4OHO1r8fB/u7v7//3@0iY6RjpmOoZGOiY5pLAA):

```
0;INżI>0ḄNMị
```

Previous [13 byter](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/A2trg4c6Fxr6PmtYc6QYSRiEPd3f///8/2kTHSMdMx9BIx0THVMckFgA):

```
0;;0ṡ3M€ċ€2Tị
```

---

#### How?

```
0;;0»3\f"⁸Ẏ - Link: list of positive integers, A
0;          - a zero concatenated with A
  ;0        - concatenate a zero
     3\     - 3-wise reduce with:
    »       -   maximum (yields a list of the maximums in each overlapping window of 3)
         ⁸  - chain's left argument, A
        "   - zip with:
       f    -   filter keep (i.e. keep the maximal if it is [in] the [length 1 list 
            -                     of the] respective original element)
          Ẏ - flatten by one level
```

Comment: Well I think there may be a way to use 3-wise reduction but I have not worked it out.

Comment: I was right - a 3-wise reduce with the maximum dyad, `»` - how about 10 though..?

Comment: [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDIOsQ7uNY9KUHjXueLir7////9EmOkY6ZjqGRjomOqZAbBwLAA). Also [10 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///obmuDQ7uNY9KUHjXueLir7////9EmOkY6ZjqGRjomOqZAbBwLAA)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing indeed, I don't think either of those were possible at the time.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
f=lambda l,*p:l and l[:p<=l[:1]>=l[1:2]]+f(l[1:],l[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBbsMgDIbvPIWVS8JmTYPQHqKxF2EcmNpokYCiJm01qe@e2WyTFmkgG/v/xC9w@Vw@Tlmv62hjSO@HABEfyhAh5ANEN5QXS1n5VzrUoL1/HDuuPEb37OU626ZpnEGNe1QaDe4oeg9wB1JJ2XnhFGpSNouw/ibYUyj/l/REqsp0S5CZQfOPH6vC8Rt4bx2rVik5bG9XV@PpG0KMpzPcYMowP80lTkvXvuVWDgJoKsmmULrjNUS8/dJ7KyVDu1xKPHaRm/TTJG7KecoL0MiktQnJpdbrFw)

I/O is with tuples rather than lists.

---

**[Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 57 bytes**

```python
f=lambda l,p=0:l and l[:[p]<=l[:1]>=l[1:2]]+f(l[1:],l[0])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDBasMwDIbvfgqRS2IqRu24PYS6L@Lp4NKFBhzHNGGl0HfPZI9BA7MQEv9n/8hKz@U2Rb2uvQ1@vFw9BEx23wXw8QrBdS7RyXJVdOaiOk2065vcEQa3J7nOtqoqZ1DjEZVGgwfOlgBewCorBxJOoWZlcxjrX4Itp6J30jIpaqZbgpkZNP/4ZVW4PEOOrWPRCmWH7eviaoi/IUQ/3eEBQ4T5Y05hWJr6M9ayE8CLGe3oU/P17QM@/uirlpJhug9xAV6MtHZEvlv69Qc)

Alt 57:

```python
f=lambda l,p=0:l and l[l<[max(p,*l[:2])]:1]+f(l[1:],l[0])
```

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica 22 Bytes

```
Pick[#,MaxDetect@#,1]&
```

Comment: Incidentally, this would also work on higher dimension arrays.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, <s>50</s> <s>49</s> 42 bytes

```
f l=[j|i:j:k:_<-scanr(:)[0]$0:l,k<=j,i<=j]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00hxzY6qybTKssq2yreRrc4OTGvSMNKM9ogVsXAKkcn28Y2SycTSMT@z03MzFOwVUjJ51JQUCgoyswrUVBRSFOINtEx0jHTMTTSMdExBWLjWAU0BYZABcZAbBiLJgEWBEnG/gcA)

`scanr(:)[0]` makes a list of the tails of `(0:l)`, each with a final `0`, e.g. for `l = [4,3,3,4]`: `[[0,4,3,3,4,0],[4,3,3,4,0],[3,3,4,0],[3,4,0],[4,0],[0]]` which is pattern matched agains `i:j:k:_` to extract all lists with at least 3 elements which are named `i`, `j`, and `k`. Keep `j` if its >= `i` and `j`.

Edit:  Ørjan Johansen saved 7 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: `i:j:k:_<-scanr(:)[0]$0:l` is shorter. (Slightly adjusting the "standard" `tails=scanr(:)[]` trick.)

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen: oh, I've used that trick before myself, but somehow missed it here. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, <s>31</s> <s>30</s> <s>28</s> <s>22</s> 21bytes

```
{⍵/⍨(⌈/=2⌷⊢)¨3,/∊0⍵0}
```

[Try it online!](http://tryapl.org/?a=%7B%u2375/%u2368%28%u2308/%3D2%u2337%u22A2%29%A83%2C/%u220A0%u23750%7D4%2C2%2C6%2C12%2C4%2C5%2C4%2C3&run)

Explanation (I'm not good at explaining things):

```
0⍵0       - [0,input,0]   (it looks like a face!)
∊         - flatten
3,/       - split into overlapping sections of length 3.
(⌈/=2⌷⊢)¨ - Whether the middle element is the maximum (applied to every section)
⍵/⍨       - index
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
p%(h:t)=[h|h>=p,[h+1]>t]++h%t
_%e=e
(0%)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7LCsMgEEX3fsUsKiTooja2i4L5EZHiwjChSZA6y/679ZHCcO/MGeaBPr3DtuUc@YBPGo3FL84mSotCuZmcEMiJvXgwgS1muPIxU0iUwIC1WsJNwkOCKlaKe9PJSbCqtP5eUFNVwZl2XEGZ0NX7ih7qBFML7Rzb/XqUm/GzHgQX2H2EBdon@Qc)

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```
a=>a.filter((e,i)=>!(e<a[i-1]|e<a[i+1]))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>84 75*</s> 71 bytes

```python
lambda l,k=[0]:[j for x,j in enumerate(l)if(k+l+k)[x+2]<=j>=(k+l+k)[x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYm9DsIgGAB3n@IbIXyDBXQw0hdBBowQ@SltCCb16ZGpicMNd7d923stonv16Nkuz5eFjEnps7npCH6tsGOEUMCVz@KqbY5kGjxJLLNE9c64uas4qyMY07caSiOeaIkcrzhxlHgZCEPp6ZhizGnwXyXK4f0H)

---

**@LeakyNun saved 9 bytes using a clever operator trick.*

Comment: `lambda l,k=[0]:[l[i]for i in range(len(l))if(k+l+k)[i+2]<=l[i]>=(k+l+k)[i]]`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

```
2ị⁼Ṁ
0;;0ṡ3Ç€Tị
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/o4e7uR417Hu5s4DKwtjZ4uHOh8eH2R01rQoDi////jzbRMdIx0zE00jHRMQVi41gFAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>15</s>  <s>14</s>  13 bytes

```
ü‹0¸«sĆÁü›+_Ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8J5HDTsNDu04tLr4SNvhRhB3l3b84f7//6NNdIx0zHQMjXRMdEyB2DgWAA)

**Explanation**

```
ü‹             # pairwise comparison for less than
  0¸«          # append 0
     s         # swap input to top of stack
      Ć        # enclose, append the head of the list
       Á       # rotate right
        ü›     # pairwise comparison for greater than
          +    # add the two boolean lists
           _   # logical negate
            Ï  # keep only elements of input that are true in the resulting list
```

**Previous 15 byte solution**

```
¬s¤)˜Œ3ùεZQ1è}Ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0JriQ0s0T885Osn48M5zW6MCDQ@vqD3c//9/tImOkY6ZjqGRjomOKRAbxwIA)

**Explanation**

```
¬                # get head of input
 s¤              # get tail of input
   )˜            # wrap stack in flattened list
                 # produces the input list with the first and last element duplicated
     Œ3ù         # push sublists of length 3
        ε        # apply transformation on each triple
         ZQ      # ... check each element for equality to the max
          1è     # ... get the middle element
            }    # end transform
             Ï   # keep only elements of input that are true in the resulting list
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 44 bytes

```
pryr::f(x[(x>=c(0,x)&x>=x[-1])[1:sum(x|1)]])
```

which evaluates to the function:

```
function (x) 
x[(x >= c(0, x) & x >= x[-1])[1:sum(x | 1)]]
```

Compares `x` to `c(0,x)`, so with `x` shifted one position to the right. Also compares `x` to `x[-1]`, so one position shifted to the left. These both are `TRUE` if there is a maximum there. `&` to take the AND of these booleans. Because of the wrapping nature of R's vectors when they are not the same length, we have to truncate the result at the length of `x`, which is found by taking `sum(x|1)`. We then plug in the boolean vector, taking only the true indices of `x` and return that.

Note, because these logical operations are done with unequal length vectors, R will complain. A lot. But the correct output will be there amidst the warnings:

```
> pryr::f(x[(x>=c(0,x)&x>=x[-1])[1:sum(x|1)]])(c(4,2,6,12,4,5,4,3))
[1]  4 12  5
Warning messages:
1: In x >= c(0, x) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In x >= x[-1] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
3: In x >= c(0, x) & x >= x[-1] :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes

```r
function(x)x[c(d<-diff(x),0)<=0&c(0,d)>=0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxLCoQwEET3cxDphhLy6XFlvIi4SmhwoyAK3j6TDEEpCt4rmj6yhqzXFs913@jme46Uxj6tqsVgeAymi2SQeApmyUqRBA4DrIPgW@qZP3W2cC/Bl9rmf65bc4E0qj9q7OO@RJ67ZvkH)

2 bytes shorter than [JAD's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/132547/86301). `diff` computes successive differences; then keep only the entries greater than both neighbours.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 20 bytes

```
-.b*YqYeSN.:++0Q03Q0
```

To be golfed...

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-.b%2aYqYeSN.%3A%2B%2B0Q03Q0&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B4%2C2%2C6%2C12%2C4%2C5%2C4%2C3%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B3%2C2%2C1%2C2%2C3%5D%0A%5B4%2C4%5D%0A%5B2%2C4%2C4%2C4%2C1%5D%0A%5B2%2C3%2C3%2C4%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 68 bytes

```r
function(a)a[a==sapply(1:length(a),function(i)max(c(0,a,0)[i+0:2]))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRMzE60da2OLGgIKdSw9AqJzUvvSQDKKwDV5KpmZtYoZGsYaCTqGOgGZ2pbWBlFKupGfs/DShoomOkY6ZjrmOiYwrExpqa/wE)

Comment: `pryr::f(expression)` is a shorter way to declare a function than `function(a)expression`.

Comment: Also, `sum(a|1)` is a shortcut for `length(a)`.

Comment: See my solution for a shorter approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 67 bytes

```php
for(;$g=$argv[+$i];$l=$g)$g<$l|$g<$argv[++$i]?:$r[]=$g;print_r($r);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReZhutpKuko2QCxEZAbAbEhkZQAVMobawUa/0/Lb9Iw1ol3RasK1pbJTPWWiXHViVdUyXdRiWnBkRCZEBS9lYqRdGxQFnrgqLMvJL4Ig2VIk3r//8B)

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 51 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^
 
M!`(?<=(^|1+) )(\1\d*)\b(?! 1\2)
^¶

%`1
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JkWbS0WLK45LgctXMUHD3sZWI67GUFtTQVMjxjAmRUszJknDXlHBMMZIkyvu0DYuLtUEw///TRSMFMwUDI0UTBRMgdgYAA)

Answer (score 1):

## q, 39 bytes

```
{x where x = -1 _ next 3 mmax x,last x}
```

Comment: I've never heard of this language before. Do you know anywhere I can try or download it?

Comment: Sure, http://kx.com, docs: http://code.kx.com

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
úâH◄(☼bM•Å
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=a3834811280f624d078f&i=[4,2,6,12,4,5,4,3]%0A[1,2]%0A[1,2,3,2,1]%0A[3,2,1,2,3]%0A[4,4]%0A[2,4,4,4,1]%0A[2,3,3,4]%0A[4,3,3,4]&a=1&m=2)

It produces output as newline separated values on standard output.

Unpacked, ungolfed, and commented, it looks like this.

```
f       filter each value in input using the rest of the program; implicitly printing kept values
  x0|S  input pre- and post-pended with zero
  3B    split into batches of 3
  i@    get the i-th batch, where i is the iteration index
  |M=   is the current value equal to the max from the batch?
```

[Run this one](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=f+++++%09filter+each+value+in+input+using+the+rest+of+the+program%3B+implicitly+printing+kept+values%0A++x0%7CS%09input+pre-+and+post-pended+with+zero%0A++3B++%09split+into+batches+of+3%0A++i%40++%09get+the+i-th+batch,+where+i+is+the+iteration+index%0A++%7CM%3D+%09is+the+current+value+equal+to+the+max+from+the+batch%3F&i=[4,2,6,12,4,5,4,3]%0A[1,2]%0A[1,2,3,2,1]%0A[3,2,1,2,3]%0A[4,4]%0A[2,4,4,4,1]%0A[2,3,3,4]%0A[4,3,3,4]&m=2)

**Updated:** Just found a 9-byte solution.  Will update explanation later:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
▀▓ûa¥╓╧↨⌐
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=dfb296619dd6cf17a9&i=[4,2,6,12,4,5,4,3]%0A[1,2]%0A[1,2,3,2,1]%0A[3,2,1,2,3]%0A[4,4]%0A[2,4,4,4,1]%0A[2,3,3,4]%0A[4,3,3,4]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 37 bytes

```perl
map{$_>=$F[++$i]&$_>=$p&&say;$p=$_}@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaJd7OVsUtWltbJTNWDcwpUFMrTqy0VimwVYmvdXD7/99EwUjBTMHQSMFEwRSIjf/lF5Rk5ucV/9f1NdUzMDT4r5sIAA)